# template_redirect called twice

Tags: template-redirect

I am working of a simple redirect plugin that match the given slug and redirect to the assigned url, which i supposed to working fine.

But recently i am adding the functionality to update the stat for the visited slug and i found that my update query called twice, i checked and found that `template_redirect` hook called twice. My stat update query is applied on single time only. Here is my code:

```
add_action("template_redirect", array($this, "redirection_section"), 11);

function redirection_section() {
    if( is_404() )
        $this->uni_page_redirect();
}

function uni_page_redirect() {

        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/uni_links.php';
        $Links = new UNI_Links();

        $slug = ltrim(preg_replace('#/$#', '', urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])), '/');


        if( $Links->is_valid_slug($slug) ) {
            // Initiate with Slug
            do_action("ulr_init_slug", $slug);
            $Links->generate_links($slug);
            exit();
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Now this is how i am updating my query:

```
function slug_init_callback($slug_name) {
        global $wpdb;

        $table_slugs = ULR_TABLE_SLUGS;

        // Debug to check invoks
        file_put_contents(PLUGIN_BASE . '/debug.txt', "call \r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("update {$table_slugs} set stat= stat+1 where slug_name=%s", $slug_name);
        $wpdb->query($sql);
    }
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This means the page is running twice. Are you doing any redirection aka `wp_redirect()`? Check if anything is hooked with `ulr_init_slug` action.

Comment: i am using `wp_redirect()` for redirect to the another url.

Comment: If the *another url* is within your WordPress site. The `template_redirect` will run again. So, the hook isn't running twice. For first one it runs for your current page and the second one from your redirected page.

Comment: wp_redirect() i am using for third party link not for the same site, is it working same two time like you told?

Comment: hmm. Please add your redirection code with the question also how you hooking into it.

Comment: @Sisir now i have used `header(..)` instead of `wp_redirect()` but getting same twice call. Is there  any way to detect that hows it is running twice? I have tested everywhere that i have only one call of `add_action("template_redirect", array($this, "redirection_section"), 11);` and if i remove my redirection and just use debugging section then again its called twice.

Comment: @Sisir I found something strange, It is just with chrome browser, not with firefox and others. calling twice only in chrome not in other browsers it is make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16606/discussion-between-sisir-and-jogesh-pi).